# Amalgamated product of automatic groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

In Gersten's "[Problems on Automatic Groups](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9730-4_10)", Problem 14, he asks the following question: Let $G=A\ast_{C}B$ where $A$ and $B$ are automatic and $C$ is infinite cyclic. Is $G$ automatic?

Is this question still open? Or any progress has been made? I am no expert in automatic groups, any reference will be very helpful!

**Additional Question:** Do people know how to compute the Dehn function of G?

Comment: I believe this is still open, certainly in full generality. It has been proved in various specific cases - for example, if $A$ and $B$ are hyperbolic relative to collections of abelian subgroups, one of which is $C$.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noticing that BS(1,2) gives a negative answer if you replace amalgamated free product by HNN extension.

Comment: @NWMT Thanks. I remember I have seen this result but I can't remember where it is now.